OpenLayers and HERE Maps with "recent" API keyw no longer working
I'm using OpenLayers 6.11 is a small project successfully for many years to access OpenStreetMap, CyclOSM, Bing, and HERE Maps.
Recently, some users have reported that they cannot use HERE Maps. It was working just fine for me when I tried. I then figured out that the users with problems recently acquired a HERE Maps API key.
So I got myself a new API key, and indeed, HERE Maps was no longer working in OpenLayers. For every tile request, HERE returns HTTP 429 Too Many Requests. Switching back to my old API key makes everything work again.
Has somebody experienced this?
Is it because I use an older version of OpenLayers (6.11)?
I use the endpoint
https://{1-4}.${ld.base}.maps.api.here.com/${ld.type}/2.1/maptile/newest/
which is also used by the official OpenLayers examples. ld.base and ld.type select the map type dynamically.
I was expecting OpenLayers to work with HERE Maps, independent from when the API key was generated.

There may be a 30 tile requests per second limit https://www.here.com/get-started/pricing/limited-plan-restrictions  A full screen map could easily break that, especially with 256 pixel tiles and the preload option.
The endpoints are also outdated, it may be better to use the latest documented in https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/raster-tile-api-developer-guide/page/topics/styles.html and use 512 tileSize option in OpenLayers and tile requests https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/raster-tile-api-developer-guide/page/topics/examples/example-size.html which will reduce requests by 75%, and remove the preload option from OpenLayers to avoid further unnecessary tile requests.

Thanks, Mike, much appreciated!
I will look into this over the weekend (hobby project) and hopefully with your tips I can get this to work again. I reply as soon as I have tried this.

Based on the info kindly provided by @Mike, I was able to make this work again.
There were several changes required, in case somebody else runs into the same problem.
Change the Map Tile URL
https://{1-4}.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/$maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/$normal.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png?apiKey=${YOUR_KEY}&lg=eng
must be changed change to
https://maps.hereapi.com/v3/base/mc/{z}/{x}/{y}/png?size=512&apiKey=${YOUR_KEY}&style=explore.day&lang=en

512x512px tiles are used
the tile style is now provided via a separate style parameter
style names have changed, e.g. from normal.day to explore.day
the language parameter has changed from lg to lang and uses two-letter codes (en) instead of three-letter codes (eng)

Add the TileSize Parameter When Constructing the Source
source: new ol.source.XYZ({
  tileSize: [512,512],
  url: `https://maps.hereapi.com/v3...
  ...

so OpenLayers knows that we use 512 pixel tiles.
Old Keys and New Keys
API keys created by users years ago still work fine with the new API versions. But new keys acquired recently only work with the latest API versions.
Restrictions
The amount of free daily requests has been reduced significantly for new keys. Even when you are only testing things, you'll run into the 'too many requests' error quite quickly now.
Adding a credit card or Paypal to your account will increase the amount of free daily requests again to a usable level.
